# Proposal Software that's NOT based on a SaaS model?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does anyone have any recommendations for a proposal creation system that isn't a SaaS offering like Bidsketch or its various competitors? I know one-time purchase software is growing incredibly hard to find in this day and age, but I loathe SaaS and I'd really like to find a solution I can purchase once and host on my own server, like my current billing software Pancake App.

(Pancake, incidentally, does offer proposal creation as a feature, but it's horribly unfriendly and buggy as hell, and I hate it)

The alternative is creating them manually in InDesign the way I used to, but that was super tedious and I'd rather not revert to that. :/

Thank you for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Kind of curious why the hate-on for SaaS solutions. "Loathe" is, after all, a pretty strong statement.

Answer (score 1):

I too spent alot of time in Indesign, but recently moved my stuff to [Wave](https://www.waveapps.com/). It's free, professional & has a great UX/UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some pretty good proposal templates on [GraphicRiver](http://graphicriver.net/category/print-templates/stationery/proposals-invoices) that you can edit in Microsoft Word or Adobe InDesign. Since they're downloads, you own these assets outright and can use them forever.

Comment: "Since they're downloads, you own these assets outright" How so? Maybe you do get full rights - but if you do - it isn't because they _are downloads_

Comment: You are correct. You don't own these outright _because_ they are downloads, you own them outright because you buy them with a personal license.

Comment: "personal license" is not the same as "owning outright". A *license* would indicate limited usage permission.